# Linear Algebra over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra

We can see a direct product of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ as a free $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ module. How does the results from linear algebra change if we change from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.
Is for example the kernel of a matrix still well defined or do we need to be more careful?

Is there any reference for a book that covers this topic?

Comment: One difference is that you can have $AB=0$ with $\det A\ne0$ and $\det B\ne0$.

Comment: This question is too broad. It would be better to reformulate it as a reference request for a textbook that treats this subject (the linear algebra of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$), otherwise it should really be closed.

Comment: Many things behave the same way. If $n$ is prime, then you really end up with linear algebra. If $n$ is not prime, you have zero divisors, so the effect that Gerry Myerson is describing might occur. Still, a matrix is invertible if its determinant is invertible (i.e. is a unit in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I was reading recently that, over a finite field, the vector space is finite iff finite dimensional...

Comment: A *finite* direct product is free. This is true over any ring. I don't remember the argument, but I think that in general, an infinite product of modules is almost never free.

Comment: @tomasz Hmm, that is actually an interesting question. If we assume that all products of free modules are free, will that imply that the ring is a field?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I guess no, this should also be true for skew-fields and division rings (at least [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_module) says so).

Comment: @Babelfish I could not find anything about the statement for division rings in that link.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft the second sentence in the article somehow softly implies, that you need a non-division ring to get non-free modules.

Comment: Halmos evidently wrote a famous book called _Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces_...  I think it's a classic...